# box-shadow not working in chrome or safari

Tags: css

I'm trying to give some table cells on my website an inset shadow... However the shadow is only displaying in firefox, and not in safari or chrome. However these browsers do pick up the fact that I have told all the even rows to have a white background. I'm hoping there's any easy solution out there!

Here's the code:

```
.appdescription tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: white;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   border-radius: 2px;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="appdescription">
<table>
<tr><td><h3> Current Version </h3></td></tr>
<tr><td><a> 1.4 </a></td></tr>
<tr><td><h3> Description </h3></td></tr>
<tr><td><a>
How much of a Doctor Who fan are you? 
Do you consider yourself a Whovian?
Do you know more than your friends about Doctor Who?
Find out by taking the Whovian Test.

Developed by Fabula Studios
www.fabulastudios.co.uk </a></td></tr>
<tr><td><h3> What's new </h3></td></tr>
<tr><td><a> New Logo </a></td></tr>
```

Comment: This is because Chrome (and apparently Safari) doesn't like applying things to the **table row**. Why are you even using tables here when there's only one cell per line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `display: block;` to that CSS and it should work.

But I advise you to leave tables and completely transform that piece to a simple `<ul>`

Comment: Hmmm worked for chrome thanks :)... Still not for safari, it might be because I'm running mountain lion so the version of safari I'm using might have bugs...

Comment: and thanks for the advice on using `<ul>` I'll change that up now :)

Comment: It does work on Windows in Safari, so I think it's your version of Safari :)

Comment: Ok that's good to know :) thanks for checking, I'll mark your answer correct as soon as it allows me :P

Comment: Adding "display: block" to a table element make it behave like a regular div.

Comment: @greg Your point being? How else would you make it work, without changing the HTML?

Comment: @greg It DOES work: http://jsfiddle.net/pbKwZ/ I would like you to remove your downvote.